# Styling of Buttons not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting my buttons to appear, but their styling is not displaying and i'm not sure why.

Below is the XAML code and how it is defined in the view model.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Button> myButtons;
    public ObservableCollection<Button> MyButtons
    {
        get { return myButtons; }
        set
        {
            if (myButtons == null)
            {
                myButtons = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyButtons");
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateButtons()
    {
        List<Button> buttonsToAdd = new List<Button>();
        List<string> buttonsToAdd = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in SettingsSingleton.RowColumnOptions)
        {
            int total = item.Key;
            Tuple<int, int> rowColumn = item.Value;
            buttonsToAdd.Add((total).ToString());
        }

        MyButtons = new ObservableCollection<Button>(buttonsToAdd);
    }
```

And XAML is

```
                          <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Command="{Binding Create_Click}" CommandParameter="{Binding Content}">
                                                <Button.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NiceStyleButton}">
                                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </Button.Style>
                                            </Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
```

I also get a weird warning/error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='Button'
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

EDIT:

My Create_Click command and the functions that then get called by it.

```
    private ICommand createClickCommand;
    public ICommand Create_Click
    {
        get
        {
            if (createClickCommand == null)
            {
                createClickCommand = new RelayCommand(CreateGrid);
            }
            return createClickCommand;
        }
    }

    private void CreateGrid(object param)
    {
        Generate(param);
    }
```

And RowColumnOptions is basically just a tuple of int, int, where we define a row and column. This is used for the Grid creation. This is where RowColumnOptions gets populated.

```
public static class SystemSettingsSingleton
{
    public static Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> RowColumnOptions = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>();

    public static void SetOptions(List<string> Options)
    {
        // Let's parse our options
        foreach (var option in Options)
        {
            var rowAndColumnSettings = option.Split('x');

            // Check that we have both row and column count
            int rowCount, columnCount = 0;
            if (rowAndColumnSettings.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(rowAndColumnSettings[0], out rowCount)
                && int.TryParse(rowAndColumnSettings[1], out columnCount))
            {
                RowColumnOptions.Add( (rowCount * columnCount), 
                    new Tuple<int, int>(rowCount, columnCount) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That SetOptions method is coming from a static class.

Comment: As a note, it is not necessary to use an ObservableCollection if you never add or remove elements from the collection  after initialization.

Comment: What would I use instead? Just a list?

Comment: Just a `List<string>` or any other `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have an observable collection of Button. That's never a good idea. It's telling you it's ignoring the ItemTemplate because you are giving it controls in the collection, which is unnecessary. Then you're trying to create another button in the item template. Templates in WPF don't mean what you think they do: They don't style content, they *create* content. Don't create buttons in your viewmodel, create them in your item template. Your ObservableCollection should just provide the information the item template will need to create the buttons you want to see. Here, that's just one string.

But it turns out that your options really consist of tuples. You want to display their products in the button content, and you want to pass the tuples themselves as the command parameter. This is easy.

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> RowColumnOptions 
        => SystemSettingsSingleton.RowColumnOptions;

    private void PopulateButtons()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RowColumnOptions));
    }

    //  I don't know what your relay command class looks like, I just tossed one 
    //  together that has an Action<object>
    public ICommand Create_Click { get; } = new RelayCommand(param =>
    {
        var tuple = param as Tuple<int, int>;
        MessageBox.Show($"Parameter: {tuple.Item1} x {tuple.Item2}");
    });
}
```

And the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RowColumnOptions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- 
            The DataContext here is a KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<int, int>> 

            The product of x * y was the Key, so that's what we'll display in the button's 
            Content. 

            We could display all three values if we wanted to. 

            We want to pass the tuple to the command, and that's the Value of the KeyValuePair. 
            So we bind that to CommandParameter
            -->
            <Button 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.Create_Click, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" 
                Content="{Binding Key}"
                >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NiceStyleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Some questions linger in my mind: What if you have both "`2x6"` and `"3x4"` in that initial list of options? The first one that comes in will be replaced by the second. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: Thanks Ed. It's essentially a Command that I am using RelayCommand with to create a grid. So the Create_Click is a command, that is all setup in the ViewModel, and there is a function to execute Grid creation.

Comment: Yes (it should be). See the above code. Just a quick question - can I have the class to bind to the name of the button as well?

Comment: It shouldn't be, and won't be. It's not a property of String. Try clicking one of the buttons, then see my updated answer for the fix. Why would you need to name the buttons?

Comment: I use the name to find out what button i have selected. Not sure how else you would know. I have to keep a record of the button that was clicked itself for future reference

Comment: That's in the CommandParameter. Forget about buttons. Actually, come to think of it, `Options` is just a collection of strings, right? You should get rid of `MyButtons` entirely, and bind ItemsSource to `Options`. Can I see what `Options` is, and `Create_Click` as well? We can simplify this whole thing.

Comment: Let me edit it and post the whole thing! I edited the code originally a bit so let me change it back

Comment: Options is technically a dictionary of int and tuple so not sure how that would work for binding.... I only need to store the row/column so i know what grid to generate, and a multiplication of the two in order to display that figure on the UI...

Comment: The button not working was to do with DataContext. The DataContext in the DataTemplate is one item from the list -- how else would the template display a list item?

Comment: Sorry... this is my lack of understand of DataTemplate. My understanding of ItemTemplate and DataTemplate is pretty hazy.... I mean... it helps "create" content? Man that's new to me... I feel like a WPF noob... (well I pretty much am!). Not sure how I can solve the issue of needing row/column figure and displaying it's combined value...

Comment: I can solve the problem, if you express it clearly. Show me the input and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry... getting too excited! I have updated the code. The dictionary is basically like "4, (2,2)" "48, (12,4)" etc etc....

Comment: 4 and 48 being what would be displayed on the Button. 2,2 being row and column for our grid, and 12, 4 respectively

Comment: @uaswpf See update. No need to thank me for being awesome. It's just my nature.

Comment: Ha.. god is every WPF coder on SO vain??? Sorry I was driving. Just tested it and it works like a charm! "Some questions linger in my mind: What if you have both "2x6" and "3x4" in that initial list of options? The first one that comes in will be replaced by the second. Is that the desired behavior?" I didn't understand that part... All seems to work well?

Comment: It's a dictionary. It can only have one item with a key of '12'. Actually, since you're adding them to the dictionary with the Add() method, if you try to add a second item with an existing key, it'll throw an exception. Very few of them are as vain as I am. But they try, bless their little hearts.

Comment: Yeah don't worry the key won't ever have duplicates and I'll fail the JSON file it's reading from if that was ever the case. Right now I'm going to try and populate the grid with buttons.. fun times! Haha... yes... i've noticed they all try alot....

Comment: Ah OK, if it shouldn't ever happen, then what you've got is perfect. I'd look at populating the grid with buttons by some means similar to how I'm populating the ItemsControl (look at UniformGrid for your ItemsPanelTemplate -- you'd bind its Rows and Columns properties to viewmodel properties specifying the desired row and column counts -- no need for a 2D collection). Creating controls in codebehind is ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: Yep. I already have the nice code for it where Rows is bound to RowCount, and Columns is bound to ColumnCount. Only issue is i've been manually populating the grid because my first row and first column should be textblocks (like labels) and the rest of the rows and columns should be buttons... so i'm doing a uniformgrid.Children.Add manually whilst iterating through RowCount and ColumnCount. God knows how I'm going to somehow "bind" that so it automatically does the first row and column as textblocks and the rest as buttons :(

Comment: @uaswpf Easy. Write a DataTemplateSelector.