# DataTemplateSelector for Uniform Grid binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Going on from what Ed spoke about in my question yesterday ([Styling of Buttons not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912551/styling-of-buttons-not-displaying)) I am trying to create something where a uniform grid is populating for the first row and first column as textblocks, and the rest of the cells as buttons. Here is a drawn example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXT6F.jpg

Now, I'm not entirely sure how to bind this all. I've almost got it working using a CompositeContainer but I want to bind the row and column of the grid using the data from the ObjSource and ObjLabeller... not sure how to do that though.

Here is the code in my VM:

```
    private CompositeCollection objGridLabelCompositeCollection;
    public CompositeCollection ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection
    {
        get { return objGridLabelCompositeCollection; }
        set { objGridLabelCompositeCollection= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GridLabeller> GridLabeller = new ObservableCollection<gridLabeller >();
    public ObservableCollection<GridLabeller> GridLabeller 
    {
        get { return gridLabeller; }
        set
        {
            gridLabeller = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GridLabeller));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ObjA> objSource = new ObservableCollection<ObjA>();
    public ObservableCollection<ObjA> ObjSource
    {
        get { return objSource; }
        set
        {
            objSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjSource));
        }
    }

    private void Generate(object rowAndColumn)
    {
        // Cast our object to a tuple
        Tuple<int, int> rowColumnForGrid = rowAndColumn as Tuple<int, int>;

        // Set Row - add 1 for header
        RowCount = rowColumnForGrid.Item1 + 1;

        // Set Column - add 1 for header
        ColumnCount = rowColumnForGrid.Item2 + 1;

        ObjSource.Clear();

        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < RowCount; ++iRow)
        {
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < ColumnCount; ++iCol)
            {
                if (iRow == 0 && iCol == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (iRow == 0 || iCol == 0)
                {
                    // Create label
                    GridLabeller label = new GridLabeller();

                    if (iRow == 0)
                    {
                        label.HeaderName = iCol.ToString();
                    }

                    if (iCol == 0)
                    {
                        label.HeaderName = GridHelpers.GetRowName(iRow);
                    }

                    label.Row = iRow;
                    label.Column = iCol;

                    GridLabeller.Add(label);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create ObjA 
                    ObjA objee = new ObjA();
                    objee.Id = GridHelpers.GetRowName(iRow) + (iCol);
                    objee.Row = iRow;
                    objee.Column = iCol;
                    ObjSource.Add(objee);
                }
            }
        }

        ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection = new CompositeCollection();
        ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = GridLabeller });
        ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = ObjSource });
    }
```

The model:

```
public sealed class ObjA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int row;
    public int Row
    {
        get { return row; }
        set { row = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int column;
    public int Column
    {
        get { return column; }
        set { column = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public sealed class GridLabeller : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string headerName;
    public string HeaderName
    {
        get { return headerName; }
        set { headerName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int row;
    public int Row
    {
        get { return row; }
        set { row = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int column;
    public int Column
    {
        get { return column; }
        set { column = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the XAML in a Grid

```
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObjGridLabelCompositeCollection}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" 
                                             Rows="{Binding RowCount}"
                                             Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
                                            <Button Content="{Binding Id}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:GridLabeller}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                                </ItemsControl>
```

At the moment it appears like so... the first image is how i want it to be...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc8GI.jpg

Sorry, not enough rep to post the images.

Anyway, if anyone has any fine ideas I'd appreciate it! Maybe I need some kind of composite collection... I don't know...

Comment: Can you please add more details? What is your goal? What are the buttons supposed to do? Are they just empty like in the first image?

Comment: Hi BionicCode. We don't need to worry too much about what the buttons do (they will be selectable, draggable etc). But I have the code to do that (porting UserControl where all my code is into MVVM to be better). I have semi got it working, but I can't quite get the ItemContainerStyle to work for the grid row and column. Both ObjSource and ObjLabeller have a row and column variable. Let me update my answer so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Is the column count constant?

Comment: No it's dynamic. Let me post the code. Both RowCount and ColumnCount are binded by a dynamic value

Comment: @BionicCode see update - thanks. Everything displays fine but obviously the row and column of the ObjSource and GridLabeller are not being taken into account because it wouldn't know which Row/Column variable to bind to since they both have one

Comment: I also posted an update to date image of what I have so far

Comment: @BionicCode if you look at the link at the end to the image of how it looks now, it's interesting because looking at the live tree, A1 has a grid.column of 1 and a grid.row of 1 (I made both my models inherit a class containing row and column and propertychanged). But on the grid itself, that isn't the case....

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The example shows how to achieve a dynamic `DataGrid` where each cell is a `Button` element. You would need to slightly modify it (data types) to meet your requirements.

I recommend to use a `DataGrid` which already has column and row headers. The `DataGrid` is populated using a `DataTable`. The `DataTable` makes dynamic column generation simple and keeps the data model free from redundant data (e.g. column headers etc.).

To override the cell layout, it is required to set the `DataGrid.CellStyle`, which in this example will turn the cell into a `Button`. This modification also requires to convert the column data of type `DataRowView` to the actual display data (in this example `CellDataModel`) which then can be bound to the `Button.Content`.

To show the row numbers a second converter is required in order to generate the value for the `DataGridRowHeader`. The `DataGridRowHeader` is defined by setting the `DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle`.

**CellDataModel.cs**

```
public class CellDataModel
{
  public CellDataModel(object data)
  {
    this.Data = data;
  }

  public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
class ViewModel
{
  public DataTable GridSource { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    // Create a data set with an arbitrary column and row count
    this.GridSource = new DataTable();

    // Create column headers with alphabetic letters from 'A' to 'G'. 
    // The decimal ASCII value is converted to a string.
    for (var asciiCode = 65; asciiCode < 72; asciiCode++)
    {
      this.GridSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(new string((char) asciiCode, 1), typeof(CellDataModel)));
    }

    // Populate data table
    int maxNumberOfRows = 5;
    for (var rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= maxNumberOfRows; rowNumber++)
    {
      DataRow newRow = this.CellTable.NewRow();
      foreach (DataColumn tableColumn in this.CellTable.Columns)
      {
        newRow[tableColumn.ColumnName] = new CellDataModel($"Value: {rowNumber}{tableColumn.ColumnName}");
      }

      this.GridSource.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
  }
}
```

**DataRowViewToCellDataConverter.cs**

```
class DataRowViewToCellDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values[0] is DataRowView dataRowView 
        && ((int) values[1]) is int cellIndex
        && dataRowView[cellIndex] is CellDataModel cellModel)
    {
      return cellModel.Data;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
    throw new NotSupportedException();

  #endregion
}
```

**RowDataToRowNumberConverter.cs**

```
class RowDataToRowNumberConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values[0] is DataGrid dataGrid && values[1] is object rowData)
    {
      return dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(rowData) + 1;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
    throw new NotSupportedException();

  #endregion
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridSource}" 
            AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" 
            IsReadOnly="True">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataRowViewToCellDataConverter x:Key="DataRowViewToCellDataConverter" />
      <RowDataToRowNumberConverter x:Key="RowDataToRowNumberConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">

              <Button>
                <Button.Content>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataRowViewToCellDataConverter }">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" 
                             Path="DataContext" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                             Path="TabIndex" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </Button.Content>
              </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowDataToRowNumberConverter}">
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
              <Binding />
            </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

This example produces following output:

[image]