# UniformGrid Grid.Row Grid.Column not being adhered to

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Following on from this question ([DataTemplateSelector for Uniform Grid binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920466/datatemplateselector-for-uniform-grid-binding)), I still am not getting my Buttons/Textblocks to adhere to the row and the column that they are bound to in the view model. I will only post the XAML as I know the row and column bindings are correct (Live Visual Tree tells me Row is 1 and Column is 1 for example, but on the grid it shows otherwise...).

If you need anymore code let me know. This is the small bit of XAML.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="800" Height="400">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCompositeCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                               <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="objGrid" Grid.Row="1" 
                                    Rows="{Binding RowCount}"
                                    Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}"/>
                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
                                                <Button Content="{Binding Id}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:GridLabeller}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.Resources>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </Grid>
```

Comment: A `UniformGrid` doesn't care about the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties. You need a `Grid` with `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnsDefinitions` for setting these properties to have any effect.

Comment: Damnit really? How would I define my rows and columns count for a grid dynamically?

Comment: You can create a `Grid` in the view programmatically based on the values of the `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` properties.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid Does this not mean it's possible?

Comment: That's a UWP control.

Comment: Boo.... Any pointers to how I can dynamically create a grid with the RowCount and ColumnCount?

Comment: Do `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` change dynamically?

Comment: Yes they do. You can click a button and it'll reload with maybe you wanting 5 rows and 3 columns instead of 2 rows and 3 columns

Comment: How should I create it programmatically?

Comment: A uniformgrid lays out it's items in a predictable order, matching order of the itemssource. You could therefore use this to control which column and row an item ends up in. Is the datacontext of.

Comment: Hi Andy. If you look in my previous question of how the layout should be and how the collection of observable collections is, it's hard to fit the uniform grid around this. It worked for me when I wasn't binding and not using MVVM i.e. children.Add but I want to go down an MVVM route that is fairly clean

Answer (score 1):

A `UniformGrid` in WPF doesn't care about the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties. You need to create a `Grid` with `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnsDefinitions` for setting these properties to have any effect.

You may create a `Grid` programmatically in the view based on the values of the `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` source properties.

Comment: Creating a `Grid` programmatically in a view doesn't break MVVM any more than creating the same `Grid` in XAML. You may of course wrap the functionality in a custom `Grid` class or a behaviour if you want to reuse it across several views.

Comment: Only need to use it once

Comment: Problem is clicking a button determines how big the grid should be. Click is handled in the VM so not sure how it would make the view create the grid

Comment: Handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the view model in the view?